# How to add records to a SharePoint list using Rest API / JSON and HTML

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api, json

I have been doing a lot of research and reading and I am still having trouble understanding how to accomplish my goal.

For reference I have been here reading:

[Get to know the SharePoint REST service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom)

I have a simple **HTML** file on my web-server named **testfile.html**
that has this snippet

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>The test SharePoint htlm page </title>
  </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txttitle" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

I have a list on my SharePoint (2016) on-premise server called **testdatalist** and it has a URL looks like this:

```
https://sp.mycompany.com/Lists/testdatalist/AllItems.aspx
```

It has one column named **Title**.

I have seen samples using REST / JSON code showing how to add records, but I am not sure how to tie this all together because each example is ever so slightly different.

Simply put:

1. Do I need to have my HTML file on the SharePoint server or Can I have it on it's own web-server?
2. How can I enter something in the input box **txttitle**  on the html page and when I press the **Submit** button have it save to the list?

**OR**

Does all this need to be done within SharePoint.... for example do I need to create a Blank SharePoint WikiPage the add my textbox and button and then add in script / content editors to do all the REST / JSON coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best approach I found was the following:**

1. Create a WikiPage Library name it **MyWikiPages**
2. Create a file named  *testfile.txt*  save that in a **WikiPage** library
3. Create a new WikiPage and name it *testwikipage*

**To get this to work there are two things you need.**

- You need a js link to the jQuery library
- You can also write your REST/JSON/AJAX code in its own .js file and link to them/or it as needed.

Put this together:

1. On the **testwikipage** add content editor and link that to the **testfile.txt** the same the wiki page.
2. In the text file you can add something that looks like this sample code
   [image]
3. In the RestScript.js you can write something like this:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Test code for your reference:

```
<input type="text" id="txttitle" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$("input[value='Submit']").click(function(){
  CreateListItemWithDetails("testdatalist")
})

function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName) {
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": $("#txttitle").val(),      
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
</script>
```

If you want to get the value from input, you'd better create an editor web part or content wen part in the page.

Comment: That was a good starting point but it actually helped me get to my own answer.